# The out() function is not working

Tags: c++

In this c++ code, I have written a basic code for a queue(FIFO). But the out() function does not seem to work, which will return the oldest input into the array. When the function is called first, it works. But the second time it does not. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Queue    {
    int que[100];
    int index=0;
    int f;
public:
    void in(int num);
    int out();
};

void Queue::in(int num){
    if(index==100) 
        cout<<"Que is full\n";
    else{
        que[index]=num;
        f=index;
        index++;
    }

}

int Queue::out(){
    if(index==0) 
        cout<<"Queue is empty\n";
    else{
        if(f>=0){
            return que[--index-f];
            index++;
            f--;
        }else{
            cout<<"Queue is empty";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    Queue q;
    q.in(101);
    q.in(202);
    q.in(303);
    q.in(404);

    cout<<q.out()<<"\n";
    cout<<q.out()<<"\n";
    cout<<q.out();
}
```

Comment: You really need to be more specific rather than saying "doesn't work".

Comment: when first called it return 101.. ( q.in(101) ), but when called second time, it returns value like 101432,56723,etc.

Comment: `return que[--index-f];` after this line, nothing more in the function is executed.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: You probably should explicitly initialize `f` as well.

Comment: then how to write it?

Comment: Undefined behaviour (UB). Your function promises to return an `int`, but doesn't always do that. You need to fix that first, because UB renders a program completely unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are returning from the function before modifying f and the index. Also, the function can end without returning anything, in case the queue is full.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, your code never get's past `return que[--index-f];` So you should reorder your code so that index isn't modifed and f is modified prior to execution of that statement e.g.

```
 f--;
 return que[index-f-2];
```

The increment and decrement of your index isn't necessary, so don't do it. Even with this change, your code will not execute the stated desired behavior, your `in()` function is actually wrong too. By setting `f=index` if you add a number to the queue after you've called the out function, you'll reset the progression through it back at the initial input. Finally, your out function doesn't actually remove the first entry from the queue.

Unless there is a pressing need to not take advantage of dynamic allocation, I would suggest that you move from using an array to `std::vector`. Your Queue class would be then have a dynamic queue size that you could change when you created the object. See below:

```
class Queue{
    private:
        std::vector<int> que;
        int maxSize;

    public:
        Queue(int size=100);
        ~Queue();
        void in(int num);
        int out();
};

Queue::Queue(int size):maxSize(size) {}
Queue::~Queue() {}

void Queue::in(int num)
{
    if(que.size() >= maxSize)
        std::cout << "Que is full\n";
    else
        que.push_back(num);
}

int Queue::out()
{
    if(que.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Queue is empty\n";
        //optionally throw an error here if you really want the program to not return a number
        return 0;
    }
    int returnVal = que.front();
    que.erase(que.begin());
    return returnVal;
}
```